# Why do two UITableViews snap to a different origin?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITabBarController with three tabs to give different views of some common data. Each tab has a UITableViewController sub class in it. One displays a table with a single section (or no sections, depending on how you look at it) - i.e. I do not override `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`. The other two have multiple sections.

If I pull down and release the single section table, it behaves as I'd expect - some empty space comes into view, but it snaps back so that the top edge of the first item is at the top of the visible area:

[image: left side is mid-drag, right side is after release]
(left side is mid-drag, right side is after release)

If I do the same to the mutli-section table, it springs back to the top of the screen, hiding the first section title and the first item:

[image: left side is mid-drag, right side is after release]
(again, left side is mid-drag, right side is after release)

I've overridden the various rows, sections, titles and so on methods, but I don't see how I could have caused this visual offset. Is it a known 'feature'?

Comment: the misbehaving one looks like the tableview.scrollview.contentInset property hasn't been set to make sure the content doesn't disappear under the navigation bar. Might just be a missing tick box in a xib for the content under top bar item.

Comment: Interesting idea, but these views are created in code - I don't set/modify inset for either. But if I do modify the offset (for an intermediate class), both cases move by the requested amount, or in other words, to appear correct, the plain list should have no inset, but the sectioned list should have an inset equal to status bar + navigation bar. I might try switching to I.B.

Comment: IB gets a bad wrap but can be helpful for stuff like this :) Good luck. If i think of anything else I'll post back.

Comment: Are you using headers or cells acting as headers? I ask because I notice that the header is not sticking to the top. If indeed they are headers you are doing something that is causing the table to be located under the tabBar most likely when you add to the view.

Comment: They're standard headers - I've implemented all the UITableViewDataSource methods in "Configuring a Table View", but done nothing to alter the appearance. I've just `#ifdef`'d those out for one of the offending tables (so there's no sections) and it was still springing back to the top of the screen rather than the top of the visible area. So then I swapped the order the controllers were added to their containing UITabBarController and it's always the first that behaves correctly and the subsequent ones that reset too high. I think I need to look into UINavigationControllers with TabBars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a consequence of abusing controllers. I initially had a `UINavigationController` containing a `UITabBarController`, containing three `UITableView`s. The correct order is a `UITabBarController` containing three `UINavigationController`, each containing a single `UITableView`.